# Getting error Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up, when i am trying to select an option from dropdown

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting error "Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up" , when i am trying to select an option from dropdown. Please find my code below

```
WebElement searchID=driver.findElement(By.xpath("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderView$ctlRegistration$DropDownList1"));
            List <WebElement> searchOptions=searchID.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
            for(int i=0;i<searchOptions.size();i++)
            {
                if(i==1)
                {
                String searchIdDropdown=searchOptions.get(i).getText().toString().trim();
                System.out.println(searchIdDropdown);
                    driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderView$ctlRegistration$DropDownList1")).click();
                    driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderView$ctlRegistration$DropDownList1")).sendKeys(searchIdDropdown);
                    driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderView$ctlRegistration$DropDownList1")).submit();
                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderView$ctlRegistration$TextBox1']")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
                    driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderView$ctlRegistration$TextBox1")).sendKeys(this.getProperties(Country+"_"+UserType+"_Registration_User1"));
                    driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderView$ctlRegistration$TextBox1")).click();
                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Please let me know how this error can be resolved.

Thanks in Advance,
Manasa.

Comment: What element is it erroring out on?  Can you provide a bit more of the stack trace?  Are you confident that your xpath is correct for the initial find element?  I would also look hard at using the explicit wait vs the implicit wait.  This will allow your code to move forward as soon a the condition is valid.

Comment: I am getting at String searchIdDropdown=searchOptions.get(i).getText().toString().trim();
                System.out.println(searchIdDropdown);
                    driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderView$ctlRegistration$DropDownList1")).click();
yes the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

So a few things to note:

- If you can get them I would use IDs or Names for the elements you are
  trying to find.  Hopefully those will be much cleaner than the xpath.
- You are rerunning your find element multiple times when you could
  just use a WebElement and make your code far more readable.
- I would try to use [Explicit waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) vs the implicit ones.

So this is my best suggestion of a starting point based on the code you provided.:

```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
   WebElement searchID = driver.findElement(By.xpath("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderView$ctlRegistration$DropDownList1"));
   List<WebElement> searchOptions=searchID.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

   for(WebElement option : searchOptions)
   {
     if(option.getText().equals("drop down name"))// or since you were looking for the index of 1 regardless you can just do just to a .get(1) from the collection directly.
     {
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(option));
       option.click();

       WebElement textbox = driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderView$ctlRegistration$TextBox1"));

       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(textbox));
       textbox.sendKeys(this.getProperties(Country+"_"+UserType+"_Registration_User1"));
       textbox.click(); //is this supposed to be a submit of some sort?
```